# Running a program and recording keystrokes in C

Tags: c, keystroke

I wanted to run a binary code inside my C program (which is an interactive code) and record each keystrokes and list it in an output file. I have written the following, but seems like it is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LIMIT 200

int main() {
    while (system("my_binary")) { 
        FILE *out_file = fopen("name_of_file", "w");
        char str[MAX_LIMIT];
        fgets(str, MAX_LIMIT, stdin);
        fprintf(out_file, "%s\n", str); 
        fclose(out_file);
    }
}
```

any suggestions what went wrong here!

Comment: Well... pretty much everything went wrong there, unfortunately. `system()` is a synchronous call that blocks until the program is finished, so there's no way anything inside that `while` loop gets executed meanwhile.

Comment: @AKX wondering what would be a way out! Is it possible in C

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ubuntu

Comment: And by "interactive code", do you mean a console program, or something else?

Comment: @AKX yes it is a console program

Comment: In Ubuntu you can open a `pipe`, `fork`, `dup2` `fileno(stdout)` and `exec*` another program. You can then read the input in your first process. You could also use the `curses` library if you want to be able to read individual keystrokes within a program.

Comment: Yeah, [this tutorial seems to be about on point](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html) for that case.

Comment: This looks like wire tapping to me!

Comment: [This post/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74340/163326) from Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks @ryyker, I wanted to have this as an OS-independent functionality. Is it a recommended approach?

Comment: The suggestion in my comment is UX specific.  i.e. it uses utilities distinctive to Unix type OSs.  I avoid ever saying something cannot be done, but in this case, writing a cross-platform application (a program that can run on more than one OS.) that can monitor & store keyboard input will be difficult.  It would be simpler to go down to HW and siphon information at the HID level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a program to do this is tricky and system specific. Yet if your system has a `tee` utility, you can run this command from the shell instead:

```
tee name_of_file | ./my_binary
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. This works well in Linux when the "tee" utility is available. But I wanted to do it in C itself so that it is OS-independent functionality. Is it possible? or Is it a recommended approach?

Comment: It really depends on your use case: writing a `tee` utility is trivial: `void tee(FILE *fp) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { putc(c, fp); putchar(c); }}` but if the application whose input you want to monitor interacts with the terminal in non trivial ways or worse has a graphical user interface, more sophisticated system specific tools are required and explaining how to achieve it is well beyond the scope of a SO question.